# How to remove nodes from XML based on conditions?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove duplicate nodes from below XML based on a condition. Can someone please help me fix the XSLT I have written? Or suggest a workaround?

My requirement: Remove entire  nodes if below conditions are met.

1. If employee id has duplicate entries
2. If above condition is ‘true’, retain Worker node where in ‘Type’ is ‘Employee’. Other duplicate ‘worker’ node entry with same employee id will have ‘Type’ as ‘Contingent’.

XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Workers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <File>22.0</File>
        <Date>2014-05-31T16:20:07.000-07:00</Date>
        <Worker_Count>2</Worker_Count>
    </Header>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>12345800</Employee_ID>
            <Name>John Davis (12345800)</Name>
            <Type>Employee</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>12345800</Employee_ID>
            <Name>John Davis (12345800)</Name>
            <Type>Contingent</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>32451854</Employee_ID>
            <Name>Felix (32451854)</Name>
            <Type>Employee</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>23471732</Employee_ID>
            <Name>David (23471732)</Name>
            <Type>Contingent</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>38741297</Employee_ID>
            <Name>Sam Daniel (38741297)</Name>
            <Type>Employee</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>38741297</Employee_ID>
            <Name>Sam Daniel (38741297)</Name>
            <Type>Contingent</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Above XML need be transformed as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <File>22.0</File>
        <Date>2014-05-31T16:20:07.000-07:00</Date>
        <Worker_Count>2</Worker_Count>
    </Header>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>12345800</Employee_ID>
            <Name>John Davis (12345800)</Name>
            <Type>Employee</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>32451854</Employee_ID>
            <Name>Felix (32451854)</Name>
            <Type>Employee</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>23471732</Employee_ID>
            <Name>David (23471732)</Name>
            <Type>Contingent</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>38741297</Employee_ID>
            <Name>Sam Daniel (38741297)</Name>
            <Type>Employee</Type>
        </Summary>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

I have written below XSLT. Not sure how to add conditions in below XSLT to remove nodes contain duplicate employee id where in type is ‘Contingent’

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Workers/Worker[Summary/Type='Contingent']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above XSLT removes all Type  which has value as ‘Contingent’. But, what I need is remove nodes which has Type as Contingent only when ‘Employee id’ has duplicate entries in the XML?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a key to look up `Worker` elements by their `Employee_ID`

```
<xsl:key name="Worker" match="Worker" use="Summary/Employee_ID" />
```

This then means you can write your template match to remove `Worker` elements as so:

```
<xsl:template match="Worker[Summary/Type='Contingent'][count(key('Worker', Summary/Employee_ID)) > 1]"/>
```

Or maybe like so (i.e Check there is a second `Worker` with the same `Employee_ID`

```
<xsl:template match="Worker[Summary/Type='Contingent'][key('Worker', Summary/Employee_ID)[2]]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="Worker" match="Worker" use="Summary/Employee_ID" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Worker[Summary/Type='Contingent'][key('Worker', Summary/Employee_ID)[2]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, there is no need to match on the full `/Workers/Worker` path. You would only really need to do this in this case if there were `Worker` elements at different levels in your XML.

Comment: This solution is faster than mine when dealing with big input data. On top of that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Add another predicate (here: `[Summary/Employee_ID = preceding-sibling::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID or Summary/Employee_ID = following-sibling::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID]`) to your match expression for the dummy template.

The following template produces the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Workers/Worker[Summary/Type='Contingent'][Summary/Employee_ID = preceding-sibling::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID or Summary/Employee_ID = following-sibling::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If predicates are chained this way, *all of them* have to be fulfilled for a match, as in a logical AND.

In addition to adding the extra predicate, I also changed the XSLT version to 1.0 since the template uses no version 2.0 features. Additionally, I removed the unnecessary namespace declaration.